# Adjusting second order ODE IVP to include parameters

Tags: python, ode

I'm writing a code that's based on two cars moving at the same speed where one if the lead car and the other is the follower. There are 500 feet apart and the average length of the vehicle is 15 feet. They are both initially moving at a speed of 30 mph before the lead card decelerates at 3 mi/s^2 before it comes to a complete stop.
The given 2nd order ODE is:

(x_fc - x_lc)* (d^2x_fc/dt^2) + k* (dx_fc/dt) - k*v_lc = 0

dx_fc/dt = v_fc = v_fco

x_fc(t=0) = x_fco
Initial Conditions

## velocity of cars

```
v_lc = 30

v_fc = 30
```

## deceleration of lc

```
da_lc = -3 #mi/s^2
v_lc1 = 0
```

## sensitivity constant, k (mph)

```
k = 17
```

## distance from front of leading to front of following, d (ft)

```
d = 500
```

## average length of car, x (ft)

```
x = 15

def dxfc_dt(t,y):
    x_fc = y[0]
    v_fc = y[1]
    return [v_fc,k*(v_lc - v_fc)/(x_fc - x_lc)]
time = np.linspace(0,500,100)
z2 = solve_ivp(dxfc_dt,[0,0],time)
```

How do I utilize this to include the distance between the two cars and the deceleration of the lead car?

Comment: The distance between the two cars is there already: (x_fc - x_lc). You also need to do a second order differentiation with respect to x_lc. The first order gives you an equation with v_lc, and the second gets you an equation with a_lc.

Comment: would I need to write another function or can I include that equation under this function?

Comment: Differentiate this: (x_fc - x_lc)* (d^2x_fc/dt^2) + k* (dx_fc/dt) - k*v_lc = 0 to get your a_lc term. And then yes, you would probably want to create a new function using your newly derived equation

Comment: that's what I thought I did when I wrote the second return equation since y[1] should return v'? unless that's not related

Comment: What you have is dxfc_dt, but what you also want is dxlc_dt, and dvlc_dt